# Can't get img width and height jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm totaly confused with this piece of code. When I just load the page **imgWidth1** and **imgHeight1** are both equal to **"0"** But when I resize my window, the code works and **imgWidth1** and **imgHeight1** have the same value as the image dimension.

All help is welcome, thanks.

```
var imgWidth1 = $("#image-hover-0").outerWidth();
var imgHeight1 = $("#image-hover-0").outerHeight();

$("#hover-img-0").css("width", imgWidth1 + "px");
$("#hover-img-0").css("height", imgHeight1 + "px");
$("#hover-img-0").css("line-height", imgHeight1 + "px");

$(window).resize(function() {

    var imgWidth = $("#image-hover-0").outerWidth();
    var imgHeight = $("#image-hover-0").outerHeight();

    $("#hover-img-0").css("width", imgWidth + "px");
    $("#hover-img-0").css("height", imgHeight + "px");
    $("#hover-img-0").css("line-height", imgHeight + "px");

});
```

Comment: This can happen if the image isn't loaded fully. Are you sure it is fully loaded when you're getting 0?

Comment: because the image is not loaded yet. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript

Comment: There's the possibility this is executed too early and the image is not available when calling the properties. You could try to wrap this in a window `load` event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely due to the fact that your code is not nested inside a `$(window).load()` function call. Modify your code to the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var imgWidth1 = $("#image-hover-0").outerWidth();
    var imgHeight1 = $("#image-hover-0").outerHeight();

    $("#hover-img-0").css("width", imgWidth1 + "px");
    $("#hover-img-0").css("height", imgHeight1 + "px");
    $("#hover-img-0").css("line-height", imgHeight1 + "px");

    $(window).resize(function() {

        var imgWidth = $("#image-hover-0").outerWidth();
        var imgHeight = $("#image-hover-0").outerHeight();

        $("#hover-img-0").css("width", imgWidth + "px");
        $("#hover-img-0").css("height", imgHeight + "px");
        $("#hover-img-0").css("line-height", imgHeight + "px");

    });
});
```

Comment: beat me to it by 5 seconds

Comment: Well how OP can retrieve `$("#hover-img-0")` if the DOM is not loaded

Comment: jQuery's `ready` event does not guarantee the loading of images, only the DOM.

Comment: @Hacketo Hmm, and how do you think I could fix this?

Comment: Thanks! The $(window).load() was the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before.  But still the question is,  do you want the real size? or the size showed on the screen ?

For the first,  you should wait the image to be loaded after you can get the real size :

```
yourImage.addEventListener('onload',  
  function() {
    console.log("pic's width : ", this.naturalWidth);
    console.log("pic's height : ", this.naturalHeight);
});
```

For the second, you must encupsle it within a div and get its size.

I hope that my answer may helps you.